# Does Arya Samaj reject Vedanta?

Tags: neo-vedanta, arya-samaj

According to Wikipedia, [it is said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arya_Samaj):

> The study of Sanskrit scriptural texts which accepted the authority of the Vedas were taught. They included the Vedas, Upanishads, Aranyaka, Kashika, Nirukta, Mahabhasya, Ashtadhyayi, Darshanas.

But this is also said:

> The members of Arya Samaj reject other scriptural works such as the Puranas, The Upanishads, the Bible, and the Quran.

Comment: in one word, no.

Comment: The picture of the stamp dedicated to Arya samaj on the wikipedia page, has the words "tamasoma jyotirgamaya", which occur in the brihadaranyaka upanishad.

Comment: @LazyLubber Brihadarnayaka is chapter 14 of the Satapatha Brahmana. Therefore, it is part of Vedas as per the scriptural definitions.1) Āpastambhaśrautrasūtra 24.1.31 मन्त्रब्राह्मणयोर्वेदनामधेयम्   (mantra brahmanayoh Veda namadheyam)
2) Bodhyānagṛhayasūtra 2.6.2 मन्त्रब्राह्मणं वेद इत्याचक्षते  (mantra brahmanayoh Veda ityacakṣte)
3)śāyaṇa also confirms in his Bhāsya that the definition māntrabrāhmaṇātmakatvaṁ tāvadaduṣtaṁ lakṣaṇam is faultless. Therefore,, from the viewpoint of Arya Samaj, chapter 14 is Veda. P.S.: I am not a member of Arya Samaj but have read their books.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda If your answer to the question is No, then I beg to differ. According to my reading and personal conversations with the members of the Samaj, they reject the Vedanta. They do not even consider Vishishtadvaita or Dvaita as a genuine school. They have a certain amount of respect for Shankara's Matham and philosophy. I do not have presently the books of Dyananda with me but can bring you exact quotes against Vaishnav philosophies from his writing when I visit the library.

Comment: @user965167 Are you aware the Sayana also considers the Taittiriya Aranyaka as part of Vedas?

Comment: @user965167 Feel free to write an answer citing references.

Comment: Arya samaj doesn't believe in worship of deity, they reject birth based varna, they do not accept that Lord takes avatar but in their opinion; Ram krishna are just "mukt-jivas". Swami Dayanand also believes that moksh isn't eternal, but mukt jivas take birth. Dayanand swami presents arguments of Vigyaan bhikshu against avataar-vad. Rest of the things are much similar to Shree Ramanujacharya.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### No, they accept all the six Darshanas including Vedanta.

You can read their commentary/explanation on Brahma Sutra [here](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/DARSHAN/vedant%20darshan/p1.htm). Though Swami Dayananda Saraswati rejects the interpretation of Brahma Sutras by Adi Shankaracharya and insists on Baudhayana Vritti instead. Read [introduction](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/vedantdarshan.htm) for more information.

Linked text above is in Hindi. Quoting English text from [Satyartha Prakasha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyarth_Prakash), a book written by Swami Dayananda Saraswati, the founder of Aarya Samaja: [Chapter 3, the scheme of studies](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/chapterthree.htm#12)

> Then they should study the six Shaastraas (commonly called the six schools or systems of philosophy) with the expositions of Rishis - the enlightened great souls, the true seers of nature - as far as possible, or in the absence of these, with the help of the true commentaries of other honest scholars. But before taking up Vedant Shaastraa They should learn the ten Upnishads.** All these books should be finished in two years.

Also check the list of [books they approved and books they condemned](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/chapterthree.htm#30).

Comment: In the same link provided above it is stated:  Do you not believe in the Puraanaas, Ithihaasa, etc.?A.~ Yes, we do; but only in the true ones, not in the forged ones.

Comment: Please note the word "honest scholar". According to my reading and personal conversations with the members of the Samaj, they reject the Vedanta as understood by Vishishtadvaita, Dvaita or Advaita.

Comment: "insists on Baudhayana Vritti instead" - Did Dayananda Saraswati study Bodhayana's vritti? If so, how? The manuscripts are lost.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Yes, it's lost. I didn't know whether he studied Bodhayana Vritti. Some of its portion is quoted by Ramanujacharya in his Bhashya.