# Which are the scriptures endorsed by Swaminarayana Sampradaya?

Tags: sects, swaminarayan

While answering question, [Does Arya Samaj reject Vedanta?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/36858/277) I found the list of scriptures approved and rejected by Swami Dayananda Saraswati, founder of Arya Samaja. [Swaminarayana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swaminarayan_Sampraday) is one of the dominant sect in Gujarat, established by [Shajananda Swami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swaminarayan), also known himself as Swaminarayana.

I want to know which philosophy or doctrine they believe in and which scriptures they have approved if they disclose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, we can say Swaminarayana is a sub-sect of Sri Sampradaya of Vaishnavism. [Swami Ramananda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swami_Ramanand) was Guru of Sahajananda Swami. Swami Ramananda told that [Ramanujacharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanuja) once gave him diksha (initiation) in dream and hence he adopted Vishitadvaita doctrine of Ramanujacharya.

Now talking about scriptures, [Shikshapatri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shikshapatri) and [Vachanamruta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vachanamrut) are two core scriptures centrally in Swaminarayana Sampradaya. Sikshapatri is the only scripture believed to be written by Sahajananda Swami himself and Vachanamruta contains important preaching of Sahajananda Swami and is written by his close chief disciplines.

He accepted following texts:

- **Vedas**
- **Brahmasutras** (from Darshana),
- **Bhagavata Purana** (out of 18 Puranas)
- **Bhagavad Gita, Vidura Niti and Vishnu Sahasranama** (from Mahabharata)
- **Yajnavalkya Smriti** (out of 18 Smritis)
- **Vaishnava canto** from Skanda Purana

Quoting from [Sikshapatri](http://issousa.org/Content/scriptures/05%20English/shikshapatri%20english.pdf):

> I hold the following eight scriptures as superior and true authority on our philosophy and religion,(Sat-Shastras).
> The  Vedas,  the  Brahmasutra  of  Vyas,  Shree Bhagvata  Purana,  the  Vishnu  Sahasranama,Shreemad  Bhagavad  Gita,  the  Neeti  narrated  by Vidura  (all  the  three  from  Mahabharata)  Shree Vasudeva Mahatmiyam from Vaishnava canto of Skanda Purana and Yagnyavalkya Smriti among Dharma Shastras. (verse 93, 94, 95)

Reading Sikshapatri it sounds that he has mixed beliefs and preaching of [Vallabhacharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vallabhacharya) and Ramanujacharya.

- Endorsed worship practice of Vallabhacharya:

  > On the question of deciding the dates (days)of  fasting,  festivals  and  on  the  customs  of  daily service  (in  the  temple  )  to  Shree  Krishna,  my disciples shall follow the decisions already made by Shree Vithalnathji, the son of Vallabhacharya,the Acharya of Vaishnavas. (verse 81, 82)
- Promoting Ramanujacharya's commentaries:

  > It  should  be  kept  in  mind  that  the commentaries on Vyasa Sutra (Vedanta Sutra) and Bhagavad Gita both by Shree Ramanujacharya are accepted  by  me  as  the  sole  authority  on  my philosophical  and  spiritual  decisions.  (verse 100)
- Doctrine (Vishishtadvaita) said by Ramanujacharya whereas Lord (Krishna) and supreme adobe (Goloka) said by Vallabhacharya:

  > All  my  disciples  shall  understand  that  my school of Vedanta is **Vishishtadvaita of Shree Ramanuja**    and    my    beloved    adobe    is **Golokadhama** and the Mukti one shall desire is  to  get  the  divine  body  in  the  Dhama  just  like that  of  Brahman  and  to  render  service  to  God Shree Krishna.